# How to add a a component via button click

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I'm currently trying to make a question configuration page for an overall questionnaire, where an admin can go to the page and add new questions and it will update the list of questions.
[Current Question Layout Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qg3b.png)

In the picture ive provided it shows that i have several fields for a question, to note as well these question fields are actually apart of a component in Angular called . My question is how do i generate another component upon pressing of the add question button that will generate the component with empty fields.

Thanks